# Leveraging JQuery find or inArray method to find an item in an array

Tags: jquery

I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to use the JQuery find method or inArray method to find an item in an array.  I can't seem to find anything in the docs.

for example:

```
var items = [{id:1, name:'bob'}, {id:2, name:'joe'}, {id:3, name:'ben'}];
var found = $(items).find("[name='ben']");
```

or

```
var items = [{id:1, name:'bob'}, {id:2, name:'joe'}, {id:3, name:'ben'}];
var found = $.inArray("[name='ben']", items);
```

Comment: You can also use `$.grep`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364307

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the RichArray plugin and more specifically

```
$.RichArray.filter()
```

You can grab it at [RichArray](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/rich-array)

Comment: The in method returns a boolean and i really need the index or preferably the item itself.

Comment: nor does the in method look much different than the inArray method of the jQuery/Utilities

Comment: The Filter function worked on the richArray plugin.  var filtered = $.richArray.filter(items, function(item) {
if (item[attr] == name) { return true; }
return false;
});
if (filtered.length == 0) { return null; }
return filtered[0];

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery find method operates on the DOM. If you try to search an array, you'll probably hit this code:

```
// check to make sure context is a DOM element or a document
if ( context && context.nodeType != 1 && context.nodeType != 9)
    return [ ];
```

That can be found in the jQuery source for the find method. It always returns an empty array if you are not using a DOM element or the document as your context.