# Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, array-of-dict

I've got an array:

```
myArray = [{'id':'73','foo':'bar'},{'id':'45','foo':'bar'}, etc.]
```

I'm unable to change the structure of the array. I'm being passed an id of `45`, and I want to get `'bar'` for that object in the array.

How do I do this in JavaScript or using jQuery?

Answer (score 2180, accepted):

Use the `find()` method:

```
myArray.find(x => x.id === '45').foo;
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

> The `find()` method returns the first value in the array, if an element in the array satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise `undefined` is returned.

---

If you want to find its *index* instead, use `findIndex()`:

```
myArray.findIndex(x => x.id === '45');
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

> The `findIndex()` method returns the index of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise -1 is returned.

---

If you want to get an array of matching elements, use the [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method instead:

```
myArray.filter(x => x.id === '45');
```

This will return an array of objects. If you want to get an array of `foo` properties, you can do this with the [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method:

```
myArray.filter(x => x.id === '45').map(x => x.foo);
```

---

Side note: methods like `find()` or `filter()`, and [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) are not supported by older browsers (like IE), so if you want to support these browsers, you should transpile your code using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) (with the [polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/)).

Comment: For multiple testing conditions would it therefore be something like: myArray.find(x => x.id === '45' && x.color == 'red').foo

Comment: For me, best answer so far. Doesn't need jQuery neither creating new auxiliar arrays.

Comment: myArray.find(x => x.id === '45') it does not work on mac PC

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I don't think that it's a good idea to copy-paste polyfills from MDN into your code; instead, you should use npm packages with polyfills. And Babel does include polyfills for ES2015+ features, in the [babel-polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/) package.

Comment: @MichałPerłakowski - I did say *"(Babel can also include polyfills for some things)"* And agreed, polyfilling has moved on since copy-and-paste from MDN. :-)

Comment: This example uses ECMAScript 6 arrow function. In case of errors when using arrow functions, there are other ways out. See
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)
and (https://dmitripavlutin.com/when-not-to-use-arrow-functions-in-javascript/)

Comment: filter actually has support back to IE9!

Comment: myArray.find(x => x.id === '45').foo;  throws an exception if there is no object with an id of '45'.

Comment: TIL .findIndex() will not work (always returns -1 even when there's a matching obj) if using a statement block, e.g.: myArray.findIndex((x) => { x.id === '45' }); ... go figure

Comment: Can I add multiple condition inside the `find` method?

Comment: yes, you can add multiple conditions. e.g const contact = persons.find(e => e.name === newName ||  e.number === newNumber )

Comment: @WhiskeyT. This has nothing to do with `findIndex`. Your arrow function doesn’t return anything. See [When should I use a return statement in ES6 arrow functions](/q/28889450/4642212).

Answer (score 1499):

As you are already using jQuery, you can use the [grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) function which is intended for searching an array:

```
var result = $.grep(myArray, function(e){ return e.id == id; });
```

The result is an array with the items found. If you know that the object is always there and that it only occurs once, you can just use `result[0].foo` to get the value. Otherwise you should check the length of the resulting array. Example:

```
if (result.length === 0) {
  // no result found
} else if (result.length === 1) {
  // property found, access the foo property using result[0].foo
} else {
  // multiple items found
}
```

Comment: It'd be safer to use `===` instead of `==`, to avoid weird issues with JavaScript's `==` operator.

Comment: @VickyChijwani: Are there any issues when comparing a string to a string?

Comment: Well, if you're _absolutely_ sure that both `e.id` and `id` will be strings, I suppose it's ok to use `==`. But if you're not sure, you might face problems (since `'' == 0` is `true` but `'' === 0` is `false`). Not to mention `===` seems to be faster (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use#comment14900957_359494).

Comment: Basically I always use `===` because it works _exactly_ like `==` in other programming languages. I consider `==` to be non-existent in JavaScript.

Comment: @de. Many answers here provide the intended behavior when looking up unique values; you can essentially recognize them by the fact that they return or break from their loop early (or instruct a lower-level construct to stop iterating). See JaredPar's answer for a canonical example, and Aaronius's comment on that answer for the same insight. In general, people differentiate between "filter" and "find" functions in this way, but terminology varies. Though more efficient, this is still a linear search, so if you want to use a hash table, see Aaron Digulla's answer (beware of impl. details).

Comment: @tne: Note that there is nothing in the question that specifically says that the id is unique, and that my answer doesn't do that assumption.

Comment: @Guffa: Indeed, your answer is absolutely correct with regard to the question as it is stated -- I just felt like pointing it out since it'll likely concern many readers who might otherwise miss an opportunity to do the right thing when they can (when the search property contains unique values).

Comment: once you have `result`, just do `myArray.pop(result)`

Comment: @mr.musicman: What are you trying to accomplish with that? The `pop` method doesn't take a parameter, so it will just remove the last item from the array and return it.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: The `filter` method is not supported in older browsers like IE 8, so using a library like jQuery is still a good option if you need it to work for as many as possible.

Comment: @Guffa Who cares about IE8 now. It's an edge case. Since you're answer is the selected as right one, a lot of novice JS devs won't know about `filter` because of your answer! You've a lot of responsibility :D

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: This answer doesn't try to list all possible solutions, it only shows the simplest and most compatible solution in the situation specified in the question. IE 8 is still too common for advocating a solution that doesn't support it, when there is a solution that is as simple and does support it.

Comment: I've created a tiny utility just for this where you can access with O(1) called [super-array](https://www.npmjs.com/package/super-array)

Answer (score 381):

Another solution is to create a lookup object:

```
var lookup = {};
for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
    lookup[array[i].id] = array[i];
}

... now you can use lookup[id]...
```

This is especially interesting if you need to do many lookups.

This won't need much more memory since the IDs and objects will be shared.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Funny how I was trying to over-complicate it by trying to loop through each time, removing each item from the list as I found it when I only needed to mutate the received data from CouchDB and get it into a format that is useful for my needs. +1 sir!

Comment: this is smart. I can't imagine how others were convinced by looking all over the array for each use.

Comment: As long as you don't rely on the order of properties: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886314/chrome-and-probably-opera-sort-object-properties-automatically

Comment: Is using a break; in the loop a good option / improvement if you know there is only one object to find ?

Comment: @irJvV: No, that doesn't make sense at all. The code above is useful if you need to do many lookups. If you look just once, then creating a `lookup` object is a waste of time.

Comment: @AaronDigulla thanks you are right. The lookup replaces the array because the objects from the array are stored under their id in var lookup. To save memory i deleted the original array with array = [ ];

Comment: I love that approach. I was looking for away avoiding the constant O(N) for every lookup. I can live peacefully with the O(N) for updates since they don't occur as often as reads are happening :)

Comment: I created a array function based on @AaronDigulla's answer. It converts the array into an object, using a given key ( Usage: myArray.toObj('id'); ) --> 

Array.prototype.toObj=function(r){var t,o,n=this,e={};for(t=0,o=n.length;o>t;t++)e[n[t][r]]=n[t];return e;};

Comment: This is great. As a side note, is there any significant benefit to setting the array len in the first statement of the for loop? I usually write it like this: (var x = 0; x < array.length; x++). Hadn't seen that before and curious.

Comment: @jbd I have to admit that I probably copied the code from somewhere. When JavaScript was still interpreted, it was probably a small speed boost since local variables are faster than indirect references. Also, it should catch a couple of problems when you change the size of the array in the loop ... which no one ever does ;-)

Comment: Just to have this noted here: With this approach you convert the object to a hashmap so you have O(n) for the first lookup (since you need to convert first) and O(1) for each following one.

Comment: Thanks for your good answer, Is this a faster way? or is this way fast enough

Comment: This is the best solution as subsequent search of a specific id will require only O(1)

Comment: I could not get the array.find or array.filter working in Pentaho Data Integration which uses the Mozilla Rhino JS interpreter. This solution works there!

Answer (score 235):

*ECMAScript 2015* (JavaScript ES6) provides the [**find()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)
method on arrays:

```js
var myArray = [
 {id:1, name:"bob"},
 {id:2, name:"dan"},
 {id:3, name:"barb"},
]

// grab the Array item which matchs the id "2"
var item = myArray.find(item => item.id === 2);

// print
console.log(item.name);
```

It works without external libraries. But if you want [older browser support](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#Array.prototype_methods) you might want to include [this polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill).

Comment: Probably cause it still seems very experimental and not many browsers support it,  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: This can be simplified to `myArray.find(d=>d.id===45).foo;`.

Comment: @Shaggy or even `myArray.find(({ id }) => id === 45).foo`. But this is an old answer that was written before ES2015 syntax was as well supported as now. @Gothdo’s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35398031/2444959) is currently the most up to date in the thread.

Comment: @Shaggy if the .find() returns undefined, then your optimization throws an error. So this solution is can be used only in cases where a match is guaranteed.

Comment: @HerbertPeters If you want to be sure you can alway null-check, which will be really easy with [optional chaining](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining): `myArray.find(d => d.id === 45)?.foo`.

Comment: This solution is for ES6 and it doesn't compatible with IE browser.

Comment: @MiladRashidi Like the answer states there is a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill) if you want older browser support. Likewise it is easy to rewrite using the older syntax.

Answer (score 148):

[Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#find) has a nice method for that:

```
myArray = [{'id':'73','foo':'bar'},{'id':'45','foo':'bar'},etc.]
obj = _.find(myArray, function(obj) { return obj.id == '45' })
```

Comment: For the record, Lo-Dash (which is often demonstrably more performant than Underscore) has a similar method. Docs here: http://lodash.com/docs#find

Comment: If you are expecting only one object, then using findWhere would be more efficient as after finding one result, the search would not go any further.

Comment: @Foreever From the docs of _.find: "The function returns as soon as it finds an acceptable element, and doesn't traverse the entire list."

Answer (score 144):

I think the easiest way would be the following, but it won't work on Internet Explorer 8 (or earlier):

```
var result = myArray.filter(function(v) {
    return v.id === '45'; // Filter out the appropriate one
})[0].foo; // Get result and access the foo property
```

Comment: I'm curious, is there any performance advantage here compared to the usual `for`?

Comment: @Igor Zinov'yev: Yes, there certainly are performance impacts with those ES5 array tools. A separate function is executed for each element, so it won't be really fast compared to a direct `for` loop.

Comment: So you're saying that it would be slower? Also, it will always scan the whole array, as far as I can see, whereas the `for` loop will terminate on the first match.

Comment: If you need support for IE8, just drop this in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153470/why-wont-filter-work-in-interent-explorer-8

Comment: This code will throw an error if there's no element with that `id`

Answer (score 81):

Try the following

```
function findById(source, id) {
  for (var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
    if (source[i].id === id) {
      return source[i];
    }
  }
  throw "Couldn't find object with id: " + id;
}
```

Comment: This wasn't worthy of its own answer, but in modern browsers this solution can be written as: http://jsfiddle.net/rwaldron/j3vST/

Comment: If you're going for efficiency, note that this example is likely faster than using filter() (see Rick's example) since this one returns once it finds the first matching item whereas filter() continues running through the full array even after finding a match. This one also doesn't have the cost of creating an additional array or calling a function for each item.

Comment: @Rick, the most interesting thing about that answer is apparently you can add the firebug console to the output window in jsFiddle.  This is so much better than logging and telling someone else to open the console to see the output. Awesome!

Comment: Since noone has mentioned it so far, I wanted to add that AngularJS also has a [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) method.

Comment: @JaredPar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44550439/javascript-search-array-of-nested-objects-and-return-parent-if-value-is-found

Answer (score 48):

```
myArray.filter(function(a){ return a.id == some_id_you_want })[0]
```

Comment: Ployfill for older browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Polyfill

Comment: @Danilo how can I search within nested object ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44550439/javascript-search-array-of-nested-objects-and-return-parent-if-value-is-found

Answer (score 36):

A generic and more flexible version of the findById function above:

```
// array = [{key:value},{key:value}]
function objectFindByKey(array, key, value) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i][key] === value) {
            return array[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

var array = [{'id':'73','foo':'bar'},{'id':'45','foo':'bar'}];
var result_obj = objectFindByKey(array, 'id', '45');
```

Answer (score 35):

## Performance

Today 2020.06.20 I perform test on MacOs High Sierra on Chrome 81.0, Firefox 77.0 and Safari 13.1 for chosen solutions.

### Conclusions for solutions which use precalculations

Solutions with precalculations (K,L)  are (much much) faster than other solutions and will not be compared with them - probably they are use some special build-in browser optimisations

- surprisingly on Chrome and Safari solution based on `Map` (K) are much faster than solution based on object `{}` (L)
- surprisingly on Safari for small arrays solution based on object `{}` (L) is slower than traditional `for` (E)
- surprisingly on Firefox for small arrays solution based on `Map` (K) is slower than traditional `for` (E)

### Conclusions when searched objects ALWAYS exists

- solution which use traditional `for` (E) is fastest for small arrays and fast for big arrays
- solution using cache (J) is fastest for big arrays - surprisingly for small arrays is medium fast
- solutions based on `find` (A) and `findIndex` (B) are fast for small arras and medium fast on big arrays
- solution based on `$.map` (H) is slowest on small arrays
- solution based on `reduce` (D) is slowest on big arrays

[image]

#### Conclusions when searched objects NEVER exists

- solution based on traditional `for` (E) is fastest on small and big arrays (except Chrome-small arrays where it is second fast)
- solution based on `reduce` (D) is slowest on big arrays
- solution which use cache (J) is medium fast but can be speed up if we save in cache also keys which have null values (which was not done here because we want to avoid unlimited memory consumption in cache in case when many not existing keys will be searched)

[image]

### Details

For solutions

- without precalculations: [A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35398031/860099)
  [B](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35398031/860099)
  [C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7364203/860099)
  [D](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30632924/860099)
  [E](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7364184/860099)
  [F](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15138786/860099)
  [G](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7364307/860099)
  [H](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7364205/860099)
  [I](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13513161/860099)
  [J](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62439978/860099) (the J solution use 'inner' cache and it speed depend on how often searched elements will repeat)
- with precalculations
  [K](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45572348/860099)
  [L](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7364247/860099)

I perform four tests. In tests I want to find 5 objects in 10 loop iterations (the objects ID not change during iterations) - so I call tested method 50 times but only first 5 times have unique id values:

- small array (10 elements) and searched object ALWAYS exists - you can perform it [HERE](https://jsbench.me/jqkbm6lgoq/1)
- big array (10k elements) and searched object ALWAYS exist - you can perform it [HERE](https://jsbench.me/u9kbm7k8dl/1)
- small array (10 elements) and searched object NEVER exists - you can perform it [HERE](https://jsbench.me/oukbmjb1e6/1)
- big array (10k elements) and searched object NEVER exists - you can perform it [HERE](https://jsbench.me/47kbmj7c87/1)

Tested codes are presented below

```js
function A(arr, id) {
  return arr.find(o=> o.id==id);
}

function B(arr, id) {
  let idx= arr.findIndex(o=> o.id==id);
  return arr[idx];
}

function C(arr, id) {
  return arr.filter(o=> o.id==id)[0];
}

function D(arr, id) {
  return arr.reduce((a, b) => (a.id==id && a) || (b.id == id && b));
}

function E(arr, id) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) if (arr[i].id==id) return arr[i];
  return null;
}

function F(arr, id) {
  var retObj ={};
  $.each(arr, (index, obj) => {
    if (obj.id == id) { 
      retObj = obj;
      return false;
    }
  });
  return retObj;
}

function G(arr, id) {
  return $.grep(arr, e=> e.id == id )[0];
}

function H(arr, id) {
  return $.map(myArray, function(val) {
    return val.id == id ? val : null;
  })[0];
}

function I(arr, id) {
  return _.find(arr, o => o.id==id);
}

let J = (()=>{
  let cache = new Map();
  return function J(arr,id,el=null) { 
    return cache.get(id) || (el=arr.find(o=> o.id==id), cache.set(id,el), el);
  }
})();

function K(arr, id) {
  return mapK.get(id)
}

function L(arr, id) {
  return mapL[id];
}



// -------------
// TEST
// -------------

console.log('Find id=5');

myArray = [...Array(10)].map((x,i)=> ({'id':`${i}`, 'foo':`bar_${i}`}));
const mapK = new Map( myArray.map(el => [el.id, el]) );
const mapL = {}; myArray.forEach(el => mapL[el.id]=el);



[A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L].forEach(f=> console.log(`${f.name}: ${JSON.stringify(f(myArray, '5'))}`));

console.log('Whole array',JSON.stringify(myArray));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>

This snippet only presents tested codes
```

Example tests results for Chrome for small array where searched objects always exists

[image]

Comment: This should be the correct answer. The performance should be an important criteria when it comes to looping.

Answer (score 30):

As others have pointed out, [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is the way to go when looking for one object within your array. However, if your object cannot be found using this method, your program will crash:

```js
const myArray = [{'id':'73','foo':'bar'},{'id':'45','foo':'bar'}];
const res = myArray.find(x => x.id === '100').foo; // Uh oh!
/*
Error:
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'foo' of undefined"
or in newer chrome versions:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'foo')
*/
```

This can be fixed by checking whether the result of `.find()` is defined before using `.foo` on it. Modern JS allows us to do this easily with [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), returning `undefined` if the object cannot be found, rather than crashing your code:

```js
const myArray = [{'id':'73','foo':'bar'},{'id':'45','foo':'bar'}];
const res = myArray.find(x => x.id === '100')?.foo; // No error!
console.log(res); // undefined when the object cannot be found
```

Answer (score 27):

If you do this multiple times, you may set up a Map (ES6):

```
const map = new Map( myArray.map(el => [el.id, el]) );
```

Then you can simply do a O(1) lookup:

```
map.get(27).foo
```

Answer (score 17):

You can get this easily using the [map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) function:

```
myArray = [{'id':'73','foo':'bar'},{'id':'45','foo':'bar'}];

var found = $.map(myArray, function(val) {
    return val.id == 45 ? val.foo : null;
});

//found[0] == "bar";
```

---

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/Pxaua/

Comment: I forgot about the fact that jQuery's `map` automatically removes `null` elements. It sounds misleading to me and to the common concept of `map`, as the result is not of the same length of the original collection.

Answer (score 17):

## Using native [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```
var array = [ {'id':'73' ,'foo':'bar'} , {'id':'45' ,'foo':'bar'} , ];
var id = 73;
```

```
var found = array.reduce(function(a, b){
    return (a.id==id && a) || (b.id == id && b)
});
```

returns the object element if found, otherwise `false`

Comment: Just a note, Array.reduce is not supported in IE8 and under.

Answer (score 16):

You can use filters,

```
  function getById(id, myArray) {
    return myArray.filter(function(obj) {
      if(obj.id == id) {
        return obj 
      }
    })[0]
  }

get_my_obj = getById(73, myArray);
```

Comment: @TobiasBeuving - The one using Array.find() is plain JS too and should stop on the first find so will be more efficient.

Answer (score 16):

While there are many correct answers here, many of them do not address the fact that this is an unnecessarily expensive operation if done more than once. In an extreme case this could be the cause of real performance problems.

In the real world, if you are processing a lot of items and performance is a concern it's much faster to initially build a lookup:

```
var items = [{'id':'73','foo':'bar'},{'id':'45','foo':'bar'}];

var lookup = items.reduce((o,i)=>o[i.id]=o,{});
```

you can then get at items in fixed time like this :

```
var bar = o[id];
```

You might also consider using a Map instead of an object as the lookup: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Answer (score 9):

Recently, I have to face the same thing in which I need to search the string from a huge array.

After some search I found It'll be easy to handle with simple code:

Code:

```
var items = mydata.filter(function(item){
    return item.word.toLowerCase().startsWith( 'gk );
})
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/maheshwaghmare/cfx3p40v/4/

[image: Serach from 20k strings]

Answer (score 8):

Iterate over any item in the array. For every item you visit, check that item's id. If it's a match, return it.

If you just want teh codez:

```
function getId(array, id) {
    for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (array[i].id === id) {
            return array[i];
        }
    }
    return null; // Nothing found
}
```

And the same thing using ECMAScript 5's Array methods:

```
function getId(array, id) {
    var obj = array.filter(function (val) {
        return val.id === id;
    });

    // Filter returns an array, and we just want the matching item.
    return obj[0];
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You may try out Sugarjs from http://sugarjs.com/.

It has a very sweet method on Arrays, `.find`. So you can find an element like this:

```
array.find( {id: 75} );
```

You may also pass an object with more properties to it to add another "where-clause".

*Note that Sugarjs extends native objects, and some people consider this very evil...*

Comment: Well, it _is_ evil, since it may happen that new EcmaScript versions may introduce new methods with the same name. And guess what, this is [exactly what happened with `find`](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-array.prototype.find). My suggestion is that if you want to extend native prototypes, always use more specific names, leaving the simplest ones to future standard developments.

Comment: this comment is nearly 2 years old and today I would rather use lodash anyways. However if you want you can read about this topic on the sugarjs website. They take a good stand to your opinion: http://sugarjs.com/native

Comment: The op did specifically ask for a javascript or jquery solution

Answer (score 8):

As long as the browser supports [ECMA-262](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#Versions), 5th edition (December 2009), this should work, almost one-liner:

```
var bFound = myArray.some(function (obj) {
    return obj.id === 45;
});
```

Comment: Almost. `bFound` is just a boolean that is `true` iff an element satisfies the required condition.

Answer (score 7):

Here's how I'd go about it in pure JavaScript, in the most minimal manner I can think of that works in ECMAScript 3 or later. It returns as soon as a match is found.

```
var getKeyValueById = function(array, key, id) {
    var testArray = array.slice(), test;
    while(test = testArray.pop()) {
        if (test.id === id) {
            return test[key];
        }
    }
    // return undefined if no matching id is found in array
    return;
}

var myArray = [{'id':'73', 'foo':'bar'}, {'id':'45', 'foo':'bar'}]
var result = getKeyValueById(myArray, 'foo', '45');

// result is 'bar', obtained from object with id of '45'
```

Answer (score 7):

We can use Jquery methods `$.each()/$.grep()`

```
var data= [];
$.each(array,function(i){if(n !== 5 && i > 4){data.push(item)}}
```

or

```
var data = $.grep(array, function( n, i ) {
  return ( n !== 5 && i > 4 );
});
```

use ES6 syntax:

```
Array.find, Array.filter, Array.forEach, Array.map
```

Or use Lodash https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#filter, Underscore https://underscorejs.org/#filter

Answer (score 7):

More generic and short

```
function findFromArray(array,key,value) {
        return array.filter(function (element) {
            return element[key] == value;
        }).shift();
}
```

in your case Ex. `var element = findFromArray(myArray,'id',45)` that will give you the whole element.

Answer (score 5):

Building on the accepted answer:

jQuery:

```
var foo = $.grep(myArray, function(e){ return e.id === foo_id})
myArray.pop(foo)
```

Or CoffeeScript:

```
foo = $.grep myArray, (e) -> e.id == foo_id
myArray.pop foo
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `Array.prototype.filter()` function.

**DEMO**: https://jsfiddle.net/sumitridhal/r0cz0w5o/4/

**JSON**

```
var jsonObj =[
 {
  "name": "Me",
  "info": {
   "age": "15",
   "favColor": "Green",
   "pets": true
  }
 },
 {
  "name": "Alex",
  "info": {
   "age": "16",
   "favColor": "orange",
   "pets": false
  }
 },
{
  "name": "Kyle",
  "info": {
   "age": "15",
   "favColor": "Blue",
   "pets": false
  }
 }
];
```

**FILTER**

```
var getPerson = function(name){
    return jsonObj.filter(function(obj) {
      return obj.name === name;
    });
}
```

Comment: how can I search within nested object ? Like pets= false should return two objects.

Comment: use `.filter` method on `obj.info` in nested loop.  
``var getPerson = function(name){
    return jsonObj.filter(function(obj) {
      return obj.info.filter(function(info) {
                            return pets === false;
                        });   
    });
}``

Comment: you could use es6 style too imo... 
const filterData = jsonObj.filter(obj => obj.name === 'Alex')

Answer (score 4):

You can do this even in pure JavaScript by using the in built "filter" function for arrays:

```
Array.prototype.filterObjects = function(key, value) {
    return this.filter(function(x) { return x[key] === value; })
}
```

So now simply pass "id" in place of `key` and "45" in place of `value`, and you will get the full object matching an id of 45. So that would be,

```
myArr.filterObjects("id", "45");
```

Comment: Don't modify objects you don't own.

Answer (score 4):

## Dynamic cached find

In this solution, when we search for some object, we save it in cache. This is middle point between "always search solutions" and "create hash-map for each object in precalculations".

```js
let cachedFind = (()=>{
  let cache = new Map();
  return (arr,id,el=null) => 
    cache.get(id) || (el=arr.find(o=> o.id==id), cache.set(id,el), el);
})();


// ---------
// TEST
// ---------

let myArray = [...Array(100000)].map((x,i)=> ({'id':`${i}`, 'foo':`bar_${i}`}));

// example usage

console.log( cachedFind(myArray,'1234').foo );





// Benchmark

let bench = (id) => {
  console.time   ('time for '+id ); 
  console.log    ( cachedFind(myArray,id).foo );  // FIND
  console.timeEnd('time for '+id );
}

console.log('----- no cached -----');
bench(50000);
bench(79980);
bench(99990);
console.log('-----  cached   -----');
bench(79980); // cached
bench(99990); // cached
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
var retObj ={};
$.each(ArrayOfObjects, function (index, obj) {

        if (obj.id === '5') { // id.toString() if it is int

            retObj = obj;
            return false;
        }
    });
return retObj;
```

It should return an object by id.

Comment: you could shorten your code by using return obj.id === 5 ? obj : false;
I use $.each a lot for iterating over arrays.

Comment: @marcel: That won't work. As returning false will end the loop, it would only find the object if it was the first item in the array.

Answer (score 3):

This solution may helpful as well:

```
Array.prototype.grep = function (key, value) {
    var that = this, ret = [];
    this.forEach(function (elem, index) {
        if (elem[key] === value) {
            ret.push(that[index]);
        }
    });
    return ret.length < 2 ? ret[0] : ret;
};
var bar = myArray.grep("id","45");
```

I made it just like `$.grep` and if one object is find out, *function* will return the object, rather than an array.

Comment: Don't modify objects you don't own.

Comment: @Gothdo I Agree. If someone didn't know `function will return the object, rather than an array` may get a mistake, but I think it depends on users.

Answer (score 3):

I really liked the answer provided by Aaron Digulla but needed to keep my array of objects so I could iterate through it later.  So I modified it to

```js
 var indexer = {};
 for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
     indexer[array[i].id] = parseInt(i);
 }
 
 //Then you can access object properties in your array using 
 array[indexer[id]].property
```

Comment: Used same solution as fastest for finding items in array. But parseInt is redundant here.

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution

```
myArray = [{'id':'73','foo':'bar'},{'id':'45','foo':'bar'}, etc.]
var bar = myArray.find(ob=>(ob.id == 45)).bar;
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from [aggaton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22943874/714240), this is a function that actually returns the wanted element (or `null` if not found), given the `array` and a `callback` function that returns a truthy value for the "correct" element:

```
function findElement(array, callback) {
    var elem;
    return array.some(function(e) {
        if (callback(e)) {
            elem = e;
            return true;
        }
    }) ? elem : null;
});
```

Just remember that this doesn't natively work on IE8-, as it doesn't support `some`. A polyfill can be provided, alternatively there's always the classic `for` loop:

```
function findElement(array, callback) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        if (callback(array[i])) return array[i];
    return null;
});
```

It's actually faster and more compact. But if you don't want to reinvent the wheel, I suggest using an utility library like underscore or lodash.

Answer (score 0):

Shortest,

```
var theAnswerObj = _.findWhere(array, {id : 42});
```

Comment: This requires using the underscore library, the OP asked for a plain javascript or jQuery solution

Comment: once you include underscore, this is not a short answer!

Answer (score 0):

The below code will help you to search values from nested objects also in your data.

```
const updatedData = myArrayOfObjects.filter((obj: any) => Object.values(obj).some((val: any) => {
   if (typeof (val) == typeof ("str")) {
      return val.toString().includes(Search)
   } else {
      return Object.values(val).some((newval: any) => {
         if (newval !== null) {
            return newval.toString().includes(Search)
         }
      })
   }
}))
```

Answer (score -2):

Consider "axesOptions" to be array of objects with an object format being
{:field_type => 2, :fields => [1,3,4]}

```
function getFieldOptions(axesOptions,choice){
  var fields=[]
  axesOptions.each(function(item){
    if(item.field_type == choice)
        fields= hashToArray(item.fields)
  });
  return fields;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

My way to find index of array:

```
index = myArray.map((i) => i.id).indexOf(value_of_id);
item = myArray[index];
```

Answer (score -7):

Use the filter method of jQuery:

```
 $(myArray).filter(function()
 {
     return this.id == desiredId;
 }).first();
```

That will return the first element with the specified Id.

It also has the benefit of a nice C# LINQ looking format.

Comment: The `filter` method is intended for elements, not arrays. Use the `grep` method instead.